# Send Mail in YII

Tags: php, email, yii

I am using YiiMail extension to send mails.

I have used the default contact.php file as my view.

mycontroller--

```
public function SendMail()
{
    //$subject = $_POST["subject"]; gives error on adding this line 
    mail('to-mailid',"some Subject","some Message",'$headers');
}
```

1) When I run this, mail is been sent to the id. It comes under spam folder with my system name as the sender. Where should I add the from address from which the mail should be sent?

2) A mail is received with subject and message that is written in the controller. I'm not getting any subject/message that I give in the field values.
For this I have tried using the following in my SendMail() function

```
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
```

It then gives an undefined variable:$subject.

Comment: `'$headers'` is wrong. `'`-quoted strings do NOT interpolate values, you're trying to set the literal word `$`, `h`, `e`, etc... as your headers.

Comment: Okay! How can I get the value from the fields? $_POST["fieldname"] is giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not

```
mail('to-mailid',"some Subject","some Message",'$headers');
```

use

```
$headers="From: sender@myowndomain.com\r\nReply-To: sender@myowndomain.com";
mail('myuser@hisdomain.com', "some Subject", "some Message",$headers);
```

You will have to set your headers correctly. I used an example.

To solve the $_POST['subject'] issue, look again at your form code. If it is a Yii form, the usage is most probably something like, where the 'ContactForm will depend on your form settings.

```
$subject = $_POST['ContactForm]["subject"];
```